# freebsd installs blender without cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

FreeBSD installs blender without cycles; but I assume cycles is just an addon.  Does anybody know the way to get it on there?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration for blender on FreeBSD does not include cycles. If you install using `pkg install graphics/blender` then it will not be enabled.

To enable cycles you will need to compile blender yourself (assuming you have [ports installed](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html)).

```
cd /usr/ports/graphics/blender
make config
(enable cycles in the menu)
make install clean
```

Note that building blender might require other ports that you may not have installed yet (like devel/llvm34 if you also enable CYCLESOSL), these can be installed using `pkg install` instead of compiling them yourself.

After the `make config` step you can use `make build-depends-list` to see what is needed to build and check if you have them installed.

Cycles was [disabled by default](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports?view=revision&revision=361268) as there is sometimes an assert from boost that causes the build to fail. I find this only happens when generating the man page which can be removed from the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.77a and earlier version build without problem but it doesn't run if Cycles engine is enabled which make not so much usable on FreeBSD.